# Suggested edit rejected as spam bumps question to the front page

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits, spam, bump

Today I saw this question in the front page of Meta:

[StackOverflow has become useless for me : |](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50620/stackoverflow-has-become-useless-for-me)

Some user seemed to have edited it 6 hours ago, as the question footer said in the front page: "discussion 6h ago [user221135](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/221135/user221135) 1". But in the question history I saw no such activity. Nothing seemed to have happened in that question since long ago.

What had *actually* happened was that the user, who didn't have edit rights, spammed an old answer of mine. His suggested edit [got rejected as spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/14009) by two other users. In the end, nothing changed.

So a spam suggested edit made a question bump to the front page. I see this as an incorrect behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was not bumped due to rejected suggested edit. But actually that user added [a spam answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178837/187824) which was deleted by community.

First he added an answer at `2013-05-03 00:55:20Z` which was deleted at `2013-05-03 01:43:57Z`. Meanwhile he suggested spam edit at `2013-05-03 01:19:51Z`

[image]

Comment: Ah! That user had also made a spam suggested edit to my answer, and that confused me since I don't have the ability to see deleted answers.

Comment: Waitaminute, Community is entirely automated, isn't it? Any idea how that answer triggered an auto-deletion? Are we not allowed to use the words "idiotic" and "stupid" in the same post?

Comment: @KyleStrand - I guess users flagged it as *it is not welcome in our community* i.e. offensive.

Comment: @hims056 Ah, didn't realize that could trigger an auto-delete; I thought it required a mod. Thanks.

Comment: @KyleStrand You need to have more than X flags for it to be auto-deleted.  The existence of certain words/phrases can make X smaller, but even without any of those keywords enough flags will auto-delete.

Comment: @KyleStrand 6 spam or offensive flags cause Community to delete things.