How can a user with no activity make a 5-year-old Stack Overflow question "active"?
A 5-year old question on Stack OverFlow, Page Navigation not working on the final for loop iteration, is currently showing as "Active" (AND displays at the top of the list) under the tag "Answers:0 [google-form]". Refer image below.



The referenced user has zero activity.
In my ignorance, I spent some time looking at the question and made a couple of relevant comments. That is, until I realised the previous comment was dated 2018.
How can such a user/question appear at the top of the "Active" list without any activity having taken place on that question?

I notice this often. Usually the user has 1 rep or is a spam account. I assume that they posted a spam answer and it got deleted but for some reason the question is still bumped. Couldn't find another post that explains it.

Found one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178859/suggested-edit-rejected-as-spam-bumps-question-to-the-front-page

Thanks, @CaveJohnson , I hadn't thought of spam. OTOH, I take the view that "there is nothing new under the sun" and that many questions have already been asked and answered - my question is a good example of this. I shall try and be more understanding to new users.

You have "last seen" in the profile (and more accurate in the network profile). So if you see activity on a post by a user that was not seen for a while, then it can be some sort of a bug.

The post is marked as recently active because there was an answer that has since been deleted.
Only users with a reputation of over 10,000 have access to moderator tools can view deleted posts.
Please refer to the screenshot. On Stack Overflow, I have more than 10,000 reputations, which allows me to view the deleted answer under the question.

The deleted entry can also be viewed from the activity of the post by users with more than 10,000 reputation points.

